# Django deployed on Heroku in admin gives error 500

Tags: django, heroku

I'm very new to python. I've deployed my beginners Django app to Heroku. Its my tutorial project. I this project I have Students, Group, Teachers app. Models are connected somehow. So there is only CRUD class-based view. When Im entering admin page its only Group is working and showing list of objects. Teachers and Group gives 500error. Through application home page everything works properly.

Comment: attach the response result from your browser inspection.

Comment: I don't actually know how to do that yet. Im using safari.

Comment: Chrome inspection, please.

Comment: did you used Procfile? if yes, show me what you typed inside it

Comment: web: gunicorn django_fedorchuk.wsgi --log-file -

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail, e.g. by running `heroku logs` if you're on Heroku.